# Error "org/apache/jorphan/test/UnitTestManager" while creating jmx file

Tags: java, jmeter, jmx

I am trying to run my java code for creating jmx file, but when I run it shows `org/apache/jorphan/test/UnitTestManager`. I have added the jar file but it is still unable to read from it. Please help

[I have added the screenshot for better clarity]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj2mg.png

Answer (score 0):

Your test project setup looks very weird, most probably you're getting errors due to some form of [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell), for example if you're using [JMeter 3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core/3.1) you should be using [jorphan 3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/jorphan/3.1) with it:

[image]

Instead of using JMeter libraries of unknown/not matching versions from your desktop I would recommend adding to your [project classpath](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-set-the-classpath-in-eclipse):

1. Everything from `c:\apache-jmeter-3.1\lib`
2. Everything from `c:\apache-jmeter-3.1\lib\ext`

or even better use a dependency-management solution like [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter-5.2/) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity